# Erro: E0254 nome de tipo não é permitido

Tags: c++

Estou recebendo este erro neste codigo:

```
bool Configuration::GetConfigBlockLine(ifstream& file, string& key, string& value)
{
    string line;

    // end of file
    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        // read line from config file
        getline( file, line );
        TrimString( line );

        // end of object's data 
        if( line.compare( "#end" ) == 0 )
            return false;

        size_t p = line.find( '=' );
        if( p != string.npos )
        {
            // key
            key = line.substr( 0, p );
            TrimString( key );

            // value
            value = line.substr( p + 1, line.length() );
            TrimString( value );

            // key - value pair read successfully
            return true;
        }
    }

    // error
    return false;
}
```

Aparentemente ele diz que string não e um nome permitido, em  `if( p != string.npos )` mas por que esse erro ocorre e como posso corrigi-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O correto é "string::npos" e não "string.npos".

No fragmento de código

```
size_t p = line.find('='); // linha 1
if (p != string::npos)     // linha 2
```

a linha 1 procura a posição (índice) do caracter '=' dentro da string "line"

na linha 2, a comparação "p != string::npos" é verdadeira no caso de EXISTIR o caracter '=' dentro da string "line".

Comment: Obrigada! Para que serve essa coisa?

Comment: ops, veja nova edição, com a resposta corrigida